# Problems with scala compiling(2.11 version)

Tags: scala, sbt

Here is full stack trace

```
Error: sbt.compiler.CompileFailed
Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.11.4-51.0'
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:117)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:114)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:281)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:114)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:281)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:31)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:65)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$2.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$2.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:20)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:19)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:118)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:100)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:536)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:100)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:99)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:99)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:98)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder.doBuild(ScalaBuilder.scala:98)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder.build(ScalaBuilder.scala:68)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderService$ScalaBuilderDecorator.build(ScalaBuilderService.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1018)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:742)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:790)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:705)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:314)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:179)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:220)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**What is may be wrong with my envirnment?
I does not post here code becose i think that code in this case does not have mean, but the same project good run on others machines.**

Answer (score 0):

Changing JDK to 1.7

Now I have 
scala.version 2.10.0, Java 1.7.0_71
in intellij solved it for me. Works Fine!